# big query with empty suffix selects from wrong table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple query

```
select * from `my_project.my_dataset.*`
                    where 
                     _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'Android_ad_revenue_raw_20210428'
```

which works normally.
Then I'm creating another table called `ios_daily_report_20210505`

My problem is When I run the above query again it returns me columns of `ios_daily_report_20210505` with null rows.

But if I run a bit modified query in which `_TABLE_SUFFIX` is not empty like this

```
    select * from `lovely-pets-2-dog-world-173288.appsflyer.A*`
                    where 
                     _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'ndroid_ad_revenue_raw_20210428'
```

It selects normally from `Android_ad_revenue_raw_20210428` table.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#best_practices) says
you can use an empty prefix and the table wildcard, which means that the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column contains full table names.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because when you do this:

```sql
SELECT
  * 
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.*`
```

You open the door to grab all columns available in the dataset, so then when you filter by:

```sql
_TABLE_SUFFIX = 'Android_ad_revenue_raw_20210428'
```

The engine already picked and merge columns from "Android_ad_revenue_raw_" AND "ios_daily_report_".

To prevent this, put ios table into another dataset or always filter the dataset before hand, as you did here:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM `project.dataset.A*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'ndroid_ad_revenue_raw_20210428'
```

Answer (score 0):

Public Documentation below:
[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation.

In [1] it specifies that BigQuery uses the schema for the most recently created table that matches the wildcard as the schema for the wildcard table. If the schema is inconsistent across tables matched by the wildcard table, BigQuery returns an error.

So the schema should be consistent if not then it returns error and as said above its better to have the tables in different datasets.